# convergence in law exercise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

I have this exercise

Let $(Xn)$ be a sequence of r.v whose distribution is defined for $n \in N^*$ by

$P\left(X_n=1-\frac{1}{n}\right)= P\left(X_n= 1+\frac{1}{n}\right) =  \frac{1}{2}$

Study its convergence in law.

======================================

The solution that I find but can't understand

For any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that for $n > N$ we have $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon $ and then :

$\mathbb{P} (|X_n -1| < \epsilon) =\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}= 1$

Therefore, $\mathbb{P}(|X_n - 1| < \epsilon)  \rightarrow 1$ when $n \rightarrow  \infty $ which shows that the sequence (Xn) converges in probability to the certain r.v. $X = 1$, and thus also in law since the limit is a constant.

However, $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = 0$ for any integer n and thus $\mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) \rightarrow 0$ when
$n \rightarrow \infty$ while $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = 1$. Thus, one must be careful in using sufficient conditions for convergence in law

======================================

My questions are :

1-how did they find that $\mathbb{P} (|X_n -1| < \epsilon) =\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}= 1$.

2-Which sufficient condition is not checked .

Answer (score 1):

1- $\mathbb P(\lvert X_n -1 \rvert \leq 1/n) = 1$. Hence given $\varepsilon>0$, we have $\mathbb P(\lvert X_n-1\rvert <\varepsilon)\to 1$.

2- Convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, and the converse is true in the special case $X_n \Rightarrow c$, for some constant $c$. Here, what they are talking about is how $\mathbb P(X_n = 1) = 0$, yet $\mathbb P(X_{\infty}=1) = \mathbb P(1=1)=1$. This is okay because $X_n \Rightarrow X_{\infty}$ means $F_{X_n}(x) \to F_{X_{\infty}}(x)$ for every point of continuity $x$ of the distribution function of $X_{\infty}$. Here, because $\mathbb P(X_{\infty}=1) >0$, $1$ is a point of discontinuity of the distribution function of $X_{\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, if you can explain to me,  why do have $p(X_\infty=1)>0 $, and  why 1 is a point of discontinuity @Andrew Zhang

Comment: @bntaous I am using $X_{\infty}$ to denote the limit, which is 1. So $\mathbb P(1 = 1) = 1>0$. For any random variable $X$, the distribution function $F_X$ is discontinuous at $x$ if and only if $\mathbb P(X= x)>0$.

Comment: Thank you for your help  @Andrew Zhang